# Flutter camera android throw exception The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, camera

I have build apps for presence for staff, and using camera for WFH. Use Dart and Flutter for Android and IOS. My apps return an exception and not showing camera activity

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)
```

using this package [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)

```
camera: ^0.9.2+2
```

here my code

```
// Using the Camera package

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CameraApp(),
        floatingActionButton: null,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CameraAppState createState() => CameraAppState();
}

class CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  CameraController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }

      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(270 / 360),
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }
}
```

i think because they had to request permission, but when i am granted the permission (from setting) it still doesn't work. i have modificate the code put this

```
cameras = await availableCameras();
```

inside the init state, hot reload then it will request the permission. then i grant permission. still not work. then return the code i've change. boom. the code is working and show the camera

i don't know what is happen.

Comment: Do you use iOS Simulator for running the application?

Comment: not yet, i am using android (both emulator & device). After this finish, will try on ios device.

Comment: I think error happening when you are getting first element from 'cameras' list (cameras[0]), just print the length of the cameras in initState before accessing the first element, to make sure list is not empty.

Comment: whoa, thankyou @TornikeKurdadze now i know the problem. 

Note : move `cameras = await availableCameras();` to new func call it in init state to solve